# What is purpose of Map interface in android using volley library?

Tags: android, android-volley, android-webservice

I have use the below code to implement the login system for my app. I have use “Map” Method. What is the purpose/function of the “Map” Method?

```
@Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to post some data to a remote server we have to override `getParams()` method. In the Request class, `getParams()` is a method that returns null.

If we want to post some params, we have to return a Map with key value pair. In this case, we can override this method and sending three parameters `tag`, `email`, `password`:

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
      // Posting parameters to login url
      Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
      params.put("tag", "login");
      params.put("email", email);
      params.put("password", password);
      return params;
}
```

In this case, we create a key called `tag` and pass the value `login` stored in param parameter.

**Note:** Notice that the `getParams()` is only called (by default) in a `POST` or `PUT` request, but not in a `GET` request.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I think to post body data, he needs to override `getBody()` instead of `getParams()`

Comment: To add custom headers Parameters to request, we need to use getParams() method.